# Fail2ban failed to match date format

Tags: regex, date, format, match, fail2ban

I'm currently optimizing my fail2ban filter.

Before my regex was this :

```
<HOST> \- \- \[.*\] \"(GET|POST) .+ HTTP\/\d\.\d\" 40\d \d{2,5} \"(.*)\" \"(.*)\"$
```

and it was working for every line that contains a 404 error like this :

```
<HOST> - - [16/Aug/2017:14:02:33 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 6494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

After that I changed the :

```
\[.*\]
```

By

```
\[[0-9]{2}\/.{3}\/[0-9]{4}\:([0-9]{2}\:){2}[0-9]{2} \+[0-9]{4}\]
```

But now it doesn't match anymore with fail2ban whereas website like regex101 still recognize the correct patern ! (don't mind the \HOST if i didn't put the \ the word was not appearing).

I tried to change **\d** by **[0-9]** **/** by **\/** **:** by **\:**
Fail2ban always miss the lines and I don't know why..

Is someone having the same problem ? thanks ! :)

Comment: Are you deliberately escaping the two `*` at the end of the first regex? Cause that seems to stop it from working.

I was able to get it to run with your change by unescaping these: http://regexr.com/3giqc

Comment: @Bananaapple No that was before the codeblock syntax I have forgotten to delete it. my second regex works with an online tool like yours, but doesn't with fail2ban :/

Comment: Hm, according to http://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#regular-expressions fail2ban uses Python's regex flavour, and your regex works fine even when I test it against that particular flavour: https://www.debuggex.com/r/xC-YEMB4P-DM-Td2 - this leaves two options then. 1 - bug in fail2ban, 2 - typo or other oversight on your end. Have you tested the regex against their command line tool? ./fail2ban-regex --help

Comment: @Bananaapple Yes i'm already testing it with fail2ban-regex :) when I change from 1 to 2 It doesn't match.. Maybe Fail2ban extract by itself the dateformat and don't except us to specify the date ?

Comment: Note that there is a bit about datetime in the documentation for regex: http://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#date-time - not sure if that helps / even applies to your case though.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I checked your documentation but it's an already existing date format (the Apache format optional time zone). BUT I think I was quite right, I did a test character by character and when I added a date, when you want to match the date the line is no more matching, so I think the solution is to forgot the date in the regex ...

Answer (score 1):

Likely the the only pattern needed is: `<HOST> .* 404` This should be tested against actual logs. The fail2ban-regex command line utility is very useful for testing.

Note that there would possibly be false positives, so it would be easier to move the response code after the host, and then have the date/time after that, in which case `^<HOST> 404` would be more precise.

Regarding performance, it seems this would be less error prone, and as fast if not faster than the much longer. See the second link below regarding filter performance tips.

- https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8
- http://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is working yes but is it the optimal execution time ?

Comment: I've responded to the optimal execution time question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the last `+` and the trailing `]`

`\[[0-9]{2}/.{3}/[0-9]{4}:([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2} \+[0-9]{4}\]`

Also, possibly, the forward slashes `/` - depending on that particular regex interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, those symbols are already escaped but Stackoverflow removed them i'm correcting my question thanks ;)

Comment: @Levrifon you should use code formatting instead of blockquotes.